# Can you set the property in a get request?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregate

I'm trying to make a movie application using node and mongodb for back-end. And the movies have a rating property, and I created a carousel collection, that have a title property. I'm creating a list that sorts the movies by rating, but the list's title is automatically "Drama", can I do something to set it to "Best Rated Movies"?

```
    //Carousel Schema
    const CarouselSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        title: { type: String },
        genre: { type: String },
        content: { type: Array }
    },
    { timestamps: true }
    );


   

    //Get Request
   

    router.get("/rating", async (req, res) => {
  let carousel = [];
  try {
    carousel = await Carousel.aggregate([
      { $sample: { size: 10 } },
      { $sort: { rating: 1 } }]);
    res.status(200).json(carousel);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json(err);
  }
});
```

Comment: If you have a new question, ask a new question.  Don't edit your existing question into something else that invalidates answers you've already received.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can send request body in a GET request but its preferably that it doesnt have any important meaning, if you give it a meaning and parse it to the server you are ignoring this recommendation: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-4.3

Here is an example of a body with a GET request

[image: reqbody with get request]

Comment: If I add req.body.title="Best Rated Movie" it doesn't change.

Comment: what are you using for your backend?

Comment: node and mongodb, and for front end react

Comment: Can you post an example of the request that is not working for you? That will help figure out the issue, because you are always able to set properties even with GET request, the example I posted is using the same stack that you are using.

Comment: I realized that I have to create the list first, but now, I don't know how to get an array of ids instead of an array of objects. I'll edit the question now.